# How to pass multiple parameters to input's onChange handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I render collection of input elements for objects in array.

```
render: function() {
    var ranges = [];
    this.props.ranges.map(function(range, index) {
        var rangeElement = <Input type="text"
            value={range.name} onChange={this.changeRangeName.bind(this)} />
        ranges.push(rangeElement);
    }, this);

    // render ranges
}
```

this allows me to write onChange handler function:

```
changeRangeName: function (event) {
    var newName = event.target.value;
},
```

but in this handler I need id of range object I want to change. So I could change change how I create input elements in render function and change:

```
var rangeElement = <Input type="text"
            value={range.name}
            onChange={this.changeRangeName.bind(this, range.id)} />
```

Now my handler will receive range.id as parameter but now I don't have the newName value. I can get it using refs

```
var rangeElement = <Input type="text"
            ref={'range' + range.id}
            value={range.name}
            onChange={this.changeRangeName.bind(this, range.id)} />
```

This is the only solution I know but I suspect there is better one.

Comment: I'm just wondering, isn't bind within a property an anti pattern in React?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `event` argument is still passed, but the `rangeId` argument is prepended to the arguments list, so your `changeRangeName` method would look like

```
changeRangeName: function (rangeId, event) {
    var newName = event.target.value;
},
```

See [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: how to add multiple args like `function (rageId, anotherValue, thirdValue, envent)`

Answer (score 88):

I think this way is easier:

```
    <Input type="text"
                value={range.name}
                onChange={(e) => this.changeRangeName(range.id, e)}
        ...
    onChange(id, e) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I liked doing it this way as 1) my binding was in the constructor 2) It  is more readable.

Comment: I agree this is very readable. But this implementation gives a warning in the browser saying: "A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component." Any thoughts on how to avoid this warning?

Comment: The downside: a new instance of this anonymous function is create every time it renders, potentially a performance pitfall. What do you think?

Comment: @Vic it looks from some blog posts that the arrow function and binding should be avoided in the render function. I am finding hard to determine when, if it works in some instances.