# React - How to update entire dataset on text input change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onchange

I have a dataset that renders react components (a list of recipes + ingredients). The data will eventually be stored in local storage as an object. When the user clicks an 'edit' button, the text becomes text input, so that the user can edit the recipes. Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asparism/fpdua2a8/) that gives you the idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099610/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-inputs-onchange-handler), I thought I could pass to the parent the index and details of the data needing to be updated, and re-render everything based on the new changes. This does not seem computationally efficient but I'm not sure what a better option would be. Additionally, when trying to pass the details up the event chain, I get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined` (where `a` contains details of update). Can I pass multiple arguments to an onChange handler (the details, an event)? Is there a better way to save updates to data? Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asparism/ew1uro3p/) where I try to pass the details. It renders nothing; the console gives the previously mentioned error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what you are proposing, which I think is indicative of the problem. I would store all the state (recipes, ingredients) in a component. This component would also define functions to call to alter the recipes/ingredients on some trigger (maybe on submission of a form or something). You pass that function into the child components. A child component which facilitates adding a new recipe for example would then call the `addRecipe` function (or whatever) upon submission, the state would update and the rendering would update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a few problems in the code:

1st, the input was the child of a recipe component, which was the child of a box component where I was trying to pass the details. I made sure the props were passing directly from prop to prop without running through functions in the recipe component.

2nd, Because I wasn't passing the data through any function in the recipe component, I bound the function at the same place where I called it (the render), instead of in the constructor.

3rd, When binding the function and passing the arguments, I passed `this` and then `data`, but when I received the arguments to the functions, the order was reversed, taking `data` first, and then the `event`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your data change is not updated is because you are not maintaining state of the component.
Your state should be like

```
this.state = {
      readOnly: true,
      open: false,
      name:props.name,
      ingrs:props.ingrs
}
```

Now, every time you update any value, that should be updated to state via setState and then react will decide if view should be updated or not.

I have made some changes in your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L6vnkvfa/1/

See how state is maintained and main update function

```
  onInputChangeIng(ele,id) {
     var ing = this.state.ingrs;      
     ing[id]=ele.value;
     console.log(ing);
     this.setState({ingrs:ing});
  }
```

Also, refer to input element

```
<input type="text" ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} onChange={()=>this.props.onChange(this.textInput,this.props.id)} defaultValue={this.props.text} />
```

Although, this is not optimised, but you get the idea how view will be updated, how state can be maintained and how multiple values are passed from child to parent.