# How do I use onChange function after getting data from redux

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem using onChange function, I got the first value (qty is 2), I need to change it, for that I'm using onChange but the value doesn't change.

I already tried to store it to state, and then called it in handlerChange but it doesn't work

This is my State and my Function

```
class Contra extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state={
            quantity1: ""
        }
        this.handleCancel = this.handleCancel.bind(this);
    }

    handleChangeQuantity(index, e) {
        console.log(index)
        let quantity1 = this.state.quantity1;
        let data = this.props.sendOpenPosValueContra;

        quantity1 = data[index].qty;
        console.log(quantity1)

        this.setState({
            quantity1 : e.target.value
        })

        console.log(quantity1)
    }
}
```

This props I got the value from redux and I need to change the qty just assume it got qty each are 2

```
{this.props.sendOpenPosValueContra.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <tr class="contentbg">
            <td style={{textAlign:"center"}}>{item.item}</td>
            <td style={{textAlign:"center"}}>{item.avail}</td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    class="tradeDisplay wide"
                    value={item.sell}
                    style={{textAlign:"center"}}
                />
            </td>
            <td style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
                {item.buy}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input
                    value={item.qty} 
                    type="text" 
                    class="tradeInput" 
                    style={{textAlign:"center", font:"bold", width:"100%"}}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeQuantity.bind(this, index)}
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    )
})}
```

I expect to be able to change the qty value

Comment: Are you referring to quantity1? If yes, how did you come to know that it didnt change?

Comment: the way you implement is bit  confusing. you should refer some tutorals or some docs. I

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass multiple parameters to input's onChange handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099610/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-inputs-onchange-handler)

Comment: @G_S i tried to store it to quantity1 but the value from redux doesnt want to change, it didnt change because i got the value there, value={item.qty} assume that item.qty has value = 2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class OPOrders extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            quantity : "",
            conditionQuantity : false,
        }
        this.handleChangeQuantity = this.handleChangeQuantity.bind(this);
    }
}

handleChangeQuantity(index, e){
        let quantity = this.state.quantity;
        let selectedIndex = index;

        let ming = this.props.sendOpenPosValueContra[selectedIndex].qty = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            quantity : ming 
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Contra extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state={
            quantity1: "",
            data: "",  //added a new property to save the `sendOpenPosValueContra`
        }
        this.handleCancel = this.handleCancel.bind(this);
    }

    handleChangeQuantity(index, e) {
        console.log(index)

        // Also, its better to keep the variable names different from state's  
        // properties. This is why, I changed quantity1 to quantity2.

        let quantity2 = this.state.data[index].qty;
        // console.log(quantity2)

        // I tried to keep your logic remains same but for me it should be 
        // like this

        // this.setState({
        //    quantity1 : quantity2
        // })
 
        this.setState({
            quantity1 : e.target.value
        })
        
        console.log('state quantity', this.state.quantity1)
    }

    // update your local state here or in componentDidMount if props are being 
    // sent to this component from parent.

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       //  ... other logic... //
       this.setState({data: nextProps.sendOpenPosValueContra})
       
    }
}
```

Comment: its still didnt work, the redux value was in array, i need to change qty in that array, in your state that was a string, and my lifecycle didnt get the props and sent it to state, is that some method that updated to state, which is not using the setState thing?

Comment: i already tried what you say but the value doesnt want to change, still get the value 2 from redux, but last time i tried the values has changed but the 2 still there , example im inputting 1 and thats be 21 when im inputing 2 thats gonna be 22